# How do I convert the protobuf train model of tensorflow I train in google colab to tensorflowjs without the use of local PC to convert?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

Hi I want to convert my exported model in google colab using google colab to tensorflowjs because after that I'm planning to deploy it in cloud storage

aside from installing !pip install tensorflowjs can anyone share or know the knowledge or steps in this one thank you so much

The reason why in google colab because my local pc can't install properly the tensorflow packages and python packages as I only have 2gb ram so everytime i do python -m pip install . In the TFOD model/research it always freezes I have been trying this for 3 months and I give up and do everything in google colab

I'm using tensorflow 2.3.1

My exported model in google colab is like this and the model file is protobuf file

exported_models
..my_models
.....checkpoint
..saved_model
.....assets
.....variables
pipeline.config

Comment: Is the model in `h5` format?

Comment: It's in saved_model.pb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you I'll update after the other batch training model is done and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

def importModel(modelPath):
    model = keras.models.load_model(modelPath)
    tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, "tfjsmodel")

importModel("<your_model_path>")
```